# How to show code in Shiny Apps using source() and from another Rscript?

Tags: shiny

I am trying to call the rScript(2) from another rScript(1). I have used source(). My question is if rScript(1) has no DisplayMode: Showcase in the DESCRIPTION file or no DESCRIPTION file, and I want to keep it that way, however rScript(2) (stored in another folder as separate app) has a DESCRIPTION file with showcase mode on, How to display this rScript(2) file's showcase from within rScript(1)? I dont want to show my source code of rScript(1) but I want the user to modify and work with rScript(2).

Second question is, is there any way to fix the "showcase with app" position and not "show below".

Thanks

Comment: You need to add a minimal reproducible example in your question

Comment: Make your question readable so that people can help you out easily

Comment: I have a shiny dashboard app running. I have a tab which has uiOutput which loads another app with histogram ,in server code  of the  dashboard app I have output$red <- renderUI({source("www\\PredictorCodes\\app.R")}), So the dashboard app loads the app.R. This app.R has permission to show the code below, in its own DESCRIPTION file (DisplayMode: Showcase
), but the dashboard app doesnot have permission to show code. When the dashboard app runs, it loads the app.R, but doesnot shows the code. I want this to be done. Please help. I am new to R.

Comment: Can this be solved by Rmarkdown or HTMLWidgets? I cannot install openCpu in Windows.